# Check if any n columns contains the same value using R?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 a    b    c    d      
 1    0    1    1      
.5    1    1    0      
.5    1   .5   .5     
 0    0    1    NA     
 0    1    0    1
```

I want to check if any of the 3 columns contain the same value so the output would look like this:

```
 val.   count
  1      1
 .5      1
```

I am trying to do this for any n number of columns. So far, I am just hard coding each scenario by using ifelse statements as shown below:

```
  t <- data %>%
        select(ivs) %>% 
        mutate(all = ifelse(a == 1 &
                          b == 1 &        
                          c == 1 &       
                          d == 1, 1 , 0),
               any_3 = ifelse((a == 1 &
                     b == 1 &
                     c == 1 &       
                     d == 0) | 
                    (a == 1 &
                     b == 1 &
                     c == 0 &       
                     d == 1) |
                    (a == 0 &
                     b == 1 &
                     c == 1 &       
                     d == 1)|
                    (a == 0 &
                     b == 1 &
                     c == 1 &       
                     d == 1), 1, 0 ) )
```

I'm hoping there is a better way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way, but the output is slightly different.
It works by

1. Using `combn` to get the combinations of the (column) vectors of `df1`, 3 by 3;
2. for each combination, apply an anonymous function that checks if all values are equal to the first, therefore all equal to one another.

Then, `table` the results and coerce to data.frame.

```
val <- combn(df1, 3, function(x) {
  apply(x, 1, function(y) if(!anyNA(y) & all(y == y[1])) y[1] else NA )
})
as.data.frame(table(val))
#  val Freq
#1 0.5    1
#2   1    1
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
a    b    c    d
 1    0    1    1
.5    1    1    0
.5    1   .5   .5
 0    0    1    NA
 0    1    0    1
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `purrr:pmap` and `dplyr::enframe`. It's a bit esoteric, but doesn't require the overhead of `combn`.

`pmap` works on data.frames row wise. We can access the row with `c(...)`. Once we have generated the counts with table, we can use `map_dfr` to subset the table to those with counts greater than our target. This would work if there were say 6 columns and say 3 were 1 and 3 were 2. `enframe` allows us to convert a named vector into a data.frame. the `_dfr` version of `map` returns a data.frame bound by row. Finally, we can tally, to count up the number of times a value has occurred anywhere in the table more than 3 times.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data %>% 
   pmap(~table(c(...))) %>%
   map_dfr(~enframe(.x[.x >= 3])) %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   tally
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name      n
  <chr> <int>
1 0.5       1
2 1         1
```

I'll leave it to you to change the rownames to your liking. A weakness of this approach is that the values become character when table is called.